# Transformations.map() returning null

Tags: java, kotlin, android-livedata, android-livedata-transformations

I am writing a Kotlin app and using Firestore as my db. I have 2 `LiveData`s, to keep my current user's data, defined like so:

```
private val userDocument = MutableLiveData<DocumentSnapshot?>()
val userData = Transformations.map(userDocument) { it?.toObject(UserModel::class.java) }
```

somehow `userData` is null, and all references to it (for example: `userData.value?.id`) throw:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.getValue()' on a null object reference
```

If I add `?` (`userData?.value?.id`) I get the `Unnecessary safe call on a non-null receiver of type LiveData<UserModel?>` lint. How can `Transformations.map(...)` return null?

btw: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968431/transformations-map-returns-null-values) similar question, but in my case, I do initialize the refered`MutableLiveData`.

Comment: where do you call `userData`?

Comment: Thanks for your fast replay! I just realized I call it in an `init` block before defining `val userData`...

Comment: I will answer the question to save time for others, because Android Studio doesn't hint that a non-null field might be null if referred before the line defining it. If you prefer, you can write that answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that I referred to `userData` before defining it. My code looked like that:

```
    private val userDocument = MutableLiveData<DocumentSnapshot?>()

    init {
        Authentication.currentUser.observeForever { switchUserDocument(it?.uid ?: "") }
    }

    val userData = Transformations.map(userDocument) { it?.toObject(UserModel::class.java) }

    private fun switchUserDocument(id: String): Task<DocumentSnapshot>? {
        if (id.isEmpty()) {
            ...
        } else if ((userData.value?.id ?: "") != id) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

I forgot that in Kotlin the order of definition and `init` blocks matters, and lost some time for that. Hope it will save that time to someone in the future:)